# Selenium2 assert questions

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2

I've recently started converting my automation suites from `WatiN` to `Selenium2`.  In both cases, I've been using `C#`.

Although these may seem like simple questions, I've been searching for answers for about 2 weeks with almost no success.

1) Is there a way to assert that an element exists?  I've had to resort to creating an abject and expecting an exception to be thrown if it doesn't exist on the page.  In `WatiN`, it was as simple as: `assert.isTrue(browser.textField(Find.ById(elementId)).exists);`

2) Is there a way to assert that text is present on the page?  I've yet to find a work around for this.  In `WatiN`, my test would have been: `assert.isTrue(browser.containsText("text"));`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` class at all. It's designed to be a bridge class to help people migrate there tests using the `Selenium RC API` (on which very little work is being done) to the `Selenium WebDriver API`. Rather, I'd use the techniques the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` class uses in my own tests.

In the case of asserting that an element exists, you had it correct the first time. Catch the `NoSuchElementException` thrown when you call `IWebDriver.FindElement()` and an element doesn't exist.

As for testing whether text exists on a page, I'd do the following:

```
public bool PageContainsText(IWebDriver driver, string textToFind)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.tagName("body")).Text.Contains(textToFind);
}
```

Though it might not be entirely obvious from looking at the `C#` bindings, these are essentially what the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` methods are doing under the covers.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't there `isElementPresent(String locator)` and `isTextPresent(String text)` function for `Selenium` object?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that I would have to create a WebDriverBackedSelenium implementation in order to use the selenium commands.  This seems much simpler now.  Thank you very much for the lead on where to look!

Answer (score 2):

In reply to your first question:

If you are using Selenium/Webdriver you can use the WebDriverWait class (see this: [link to so answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-wait-for-jquery-ajax-calls-to-complete-in-selenium-2/166#166)) or you could use `driver.FindElements(..)` as it does not throw if no elements are found. You can then use some linq magic to get the first match. So it would look something like this: `driver.FindElements(..).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know that there is a function in Selenium called `verifyIfTextPresent` that you can use.
Check this link for more info - [assertion/verification docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#assertion-or-verification)