# How do you wait for jQuery Ajax calls to complete in Selenium 2

Tags: selenium2

I use Selenium 2 in C# to automate testing of our web sites. When building non-Ajax functionality, using webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("element-id")) to find elements on a page works fine, but when doing jQuery Ajax calls this doesn't work because it tries to find the element before the ajax request has finished.

How do I tell Selenium to wait until the jQuery Ajax has completed?

Comment: I'm finding issues with this that the Wait's are not working for on one particular page I am testing.  Did you ever get a working solution for this?  I have made multiple waits and field checks on the page but nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class you are looking for is the **WebDriverWait** class that you can find here (**C#**):
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/WebDriverWait.cs

I created an extension method to make it easier to use that looks something like this:

```
public static class BrowserExtensions
{
    public static T WaitUntil<T>(this IWebDriver browser, Func<IWebDriver, T> condition, int timeout = 5)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout));
        return wait.Until(condition);
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var element = webDriver.WaitUntil(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("element-id")));
```

Note that this does not guarantee that the element is visible when you get it back!

Also I should probably mention that I have experienced problems using the WebDriverWait class and I think it could use some work to make it more stable.

Comment: I use WebDriverWait extensively and don't recall any stability issues. In Selenium2 beta2, there were definitely issues with sendKeys, so I used WebDriverWait to prevent the script from changing focus until the field contents match the sendKeys text.  Using beta3, I haven't encountered any more stability problems with FirefoxDriver or InternetExplorerDriver.

Comment: The WebDriverWait class is pretty bare-bones. That said, it would be interesting to know (in another, more appropriate forum) what you're finding about it that's "unstable".

Comment: I do use wait with success most of the time, but I do find the timings on some JQuery pages is not quite right and I either end up with errors on the field I am trying to capture as its caught but then not there.  Either I end up with Element is not displayed or Element is no longer valid.  JQuery definitely takes work with Web Driver to get things just right.

Answer (score 9):

A possibly more generic solution to this problem is to wait for the jquery to complete.  You can do this with a function like this:

```
public void WaitForAjax()
{
    while (true) // Handle timeout somewhere
    {
        var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        if (ajaxIsComplete)
            break;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I'm ripping all the Thread.Sleep() out of the tests for my AJAX-heavy web application under test now, and this seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote up an equivalent in python:  (mind the whitespace removal) `class jquery_to_complete(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, driver):
        isjQueryComplete = driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0")
        return isjQueryComplete`

Answer (score 1):

Fairly ceertain that there is a Wait class that you can access. From the docs:

> public abstract class Wait extends
>   java.lang.Object
>
> A utility class, designed to help the
>   user automatically wait until a
>   condition turns true. Use it like
>   this:
>
> new Wait("Couldn't find close
>   button!") {
>       boolean until() {
>           return selenium.isElementPresent("button_Close");
>       } };

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote my own wait_for_element method on the page objects for my selenium tests.  You will need:

- Success check function

  ```
  return element.isVisible()
  ```
- A function to define what you are getting

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("element-id"))
  ```
- Length of time prepared to wait and how often to check

This was all written before the Wait class was added to selenium 2/webdriver.  I have not yet had a chance to use the Wait class, does anyone know if it is any good?  I noticed one answer said selenium2 might need to work on it a bit

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on Stack Overflow with an excellent answer if you can consider using he PageObject model.

[Using PageFactory to init elements on AJAX pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272883/how-to-use-selenium-2-pagefactory-init-elements-with-wait-until)