# How to wait for ajax calls using a selenium command

Tags: selenium

I'm using the selenium ide to create test cases.

Will the "AndWait" commands wait for an ajax operation to complete? Is there a specific command that can help with this?

I prefer to use the selenium ide to create the tests as much as possible, I've seen [How do you wait for jQuery Ajax calls to complete in Selenium 2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-wait-for-jquery-ajax-calls-to-complete-in-selenium-2) which is similar to what I'm asking but I'm not using c# at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explicit and Implicit Waits**

- wait.until(condition)
- waitForElementPresent(locator)
- driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

More information here:
 **[Advanced Webdriver Usage with "implicit waits"](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)**